# Node.js +Vue App +Websockets, updating list of connected elements

Tags: node.js, vue.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm trying to make this app based on node+socket.io+Vue.js.
Referring to the back end I set the server connected to socket io and all referring to the different emitters :

```
Class Server

const express = require("express"); 
const cors = require("cors"); 
const corsObject = {
  origin: ["http://localhost:8100"],
  methods: ["GET", "POST", "DELETE", "PUT", "PATCH"],
  allowedHeaders: ["Content-Type", "Authorization","token-response"],
  credentials: true,
};

const { conectToMongo } = require("../database/database");

const {
  socketController,
} = require("../sockets-controllers/socket-controller");

class Server {
  constructor() {
    this.allowedOrigins = "http://localhost:8100";
    this.app = express(); 
    this.port = process.env.PORT; arranque
    

    this.connectingdatabase(); 
    this.server = require("http").createServer(this.app);

    this.io = require("socket.io")(this.server, {
      cors: corsObject,
    }); 

    this.connectionSocketClient(); 
    this.middlewares(); 
    this.routes(); 
  }
  
  middlewares() {
    this.app.use(express.json()); //lectura y parsoin del body a fomato json
    this.app.use(express.static("public")); //directorio fornt
    this.app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: "http://localhost:8100" })); //cors
    this.app.get("/", (request, response, next) => {
      response.status(200).json({
        ok: true,
        message: "request correct",
      });
    });
  }
  
  routes() {
    this.app.use("/user", require("../routes/user-routes"));
    this.app.use("/auth", require("../routes/user-login"));
    // this.app.use(this.usuariosPath,require('../routes/user-routes'))
  }

  
  async connectingdatabase() {
    await conectToMongo();
  }

  
  connectionSocketClient() {
    this.io.on("connection",(socket)=> socketController(socket,this.io));
  }
  
  portListener() {
 
 this.server.listen(this.port, () => {
      console.log(`server running on port : ${this.port}`);
  });
    
  }
}

module.exports = Server; //Exportando la clase interface creada para su uso en los demas modulos
```

In order to initialize the controllers i first set a class which might be used on controllers in a easier way importing its instance

```
class Message {
  constructor(userId, userMessage, message) {
    this.userId = userId;
    this.userMessage = userMessage;
    this.message = message;
  }
} //Class and its constructor Message

class ChatMessage {
  constructor() {
    this.messages = [];
    this.usersOnConnection = {};
  }
  //constructor of this class with two components , first a array of message 
  //and second  a object that would be stacking the connected users

  get usersConnected() {
    return Object.values(this.usersOnConnection);
  } 
  //This getter would retrieve the object of users connected converting it to 
  //an array 

   addUserToChat(user) {
    this.usersOnConnection[user.id] = user
  } 
  //this method would add a user to a chat i this case adding the new consumer 
  //to the object of users connected usersOnConnection(HERE problem too)

 }
 //Class and its constructor Message

module.exports = { Message, ChatMessage };
```

Then the socket controller on charge of set the logic would be like this

```
const { Socket } = require("socket.io");

const { ChatMessage, Message } = require("../models/chat-model");//Interfaces imported


const socketController = async (socket = new Socket(), io) => {

  const user = await jwtValidatorRenew(
    socket.handshake.headers["token-response"]
  );

 
  if (!user || user == undefined) {
    console.log("user disconnected");
    return socket.disconnect();
  }
  //if for some reason the user requested thorugh a token i retrieve is null 
  //or some like , the controller ends here with a disconnection to the socket
 

 //else
 const chatMessage =await  new ChatMessage(); //creating new isntance of class ChatMessage
 //first i do create a new instance of the class Chatmessage in order to access from here 

 chatMessage.addUserToChat(user); //adding user to the chat (HERE )
 //then any time the browser is recharged or user inits session  , this user 
 //would be added, using the method addUserToChat from the class instance

  io.emit("active-users", chatMessage.usersConnected); //sending users connected
  //once the user is added i do proceed to emit through io , the state of all connected 
  //consumers aiming to the flag "active-users", accesing the getter usersConnected
  //from the instance

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    
   console.log("Client DisconectedConected", socket.id); // desconexion
   
   chatMessage.disconnectUserFromChat(user.id);
   //diconnecting user
   
   io.emit("active-users", chatMessage.usersConnected);
  }); 
  //On disconnection the instance of chatmessage class is called in order to disconnect
  //user according to its id. Also accession io from socket I do emit for all consumers
  //a new state under the flag "active-users", passing ass method the getter usersConnected
  //from the instance chatMessage(but only receive one user)
};



module.exports = { socketController };
```

Then on my front after setting socket io client i set this on my Vue state manangement(vuex ) for the socket connection, being this action dispatched any time i need.

```
ACTIONS VUEX
 conectingSocket() {
      const socket= io("localhost:3006", {
        extraHeaders: {
          "token-response": localStorage.getItem("token"),
        },
      });

      socket.on("connect",()=>{
        console.log("socket online");
      })
      //flag on connection 

      socket.on("disconnect",()=>{
        console.log("socket offline");
      })
      //flag on discconnection 

      socket.on("active-users",(usersPayload)=>{
        console.log(usersPayload);
      })
     //Here i log the users connected updated once the back emit on this flag a action . But always 
     //brings me the user of the browser that I recharge not updating the other ones

      
 },
```

Then any time i initialize my app this method on front is triggered in order to retrieve the users
connected, thus for that simply call the method and set it also in my mounted Vue life cycle:

```
export default {
  name: "AllUsersComponent",
  components: { IonCard, IonContent, IonItem, IonInput, IonButton, IonLabel },
  // components: { IonLabel, IonInput, IonItem },
  data() {
    return {
      allUsersFinal: [],
      message: "",
      state: false,
      
      socket: io(process.env.VUE_APP_BACK_URL),
      //client socket and its connection
    };
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(["getAllUsers", "validateToken", "conectingSocket"]),


    socketConection() {
      this.$store.dispatch("conectingSocket");
    },

    ...some methods
    },
    
  },

  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["getterGetAllUsers"]),

   ...some computed methods
  },

  mounted() {

    this.socketConection() 
   
  },
 
 created() {
    ...some methods
  },
  
};
</script>
```

But keeps showing me only the user of the browser I do recharge. For this purpose i initialize on the app two users from different browsers(Firefox and Chrome)
[image]
Any help on this would be amazing!!!!!

Comment: Can you simplify your question? This is a huge information overload for someone who might otherwise be able to help you.

Comment: Hola Soy Chai , guess is neccesary expose the whole situation , and is quite clear , my web sockets don't update the list of users connected properly